# Matlab Rectangle not working after swapping x and y axes

Tags: matlab

I need to swap x and y axes and draw a rectangle. I do the swap with "view(-90, 90)" and axes are swapped correctly but the rectangle is not drawn. Code:

```
axis([1 11 1 11])
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
rectangle('Position',[5 5 1 1], 'FaceColor','k')
view(-90,90) 
set(gca,'ydir','reverse')
set(gca,'xdir','reverse')
set(gca, 'YAxisLocation', 'right')
```

When I draw something with "plot" instead of "rectangle", e.g.

```
X = (1:11);
Y = (1:11);
plot(X, Y);
```

it is drawn correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems that as soon as you rotate the point of view (even by 1 degree), the rectangle is still in the axes children list but it is not rendered. I tried with all different renderer (`painter`,`openGL`, and `zbuffer`) and it is the same behavior (*at least on my system: Matlab 2013a, win8*)

So a quick workaround is to use a `patch` object instead. I tried these and they are rendered regardless of the point of view. The properties are mostly the same, except for the rounded angle but if you don't need that you'll be better off with `patch` anyway.

If for ease of use you want to mimic the calling syntax of `rectangle`, you can package your call in a custom function `recpatch`. And if the coordinates and the color are the only things you want to set you can even use an inline function:

```
%// define an inline helper function to create a rectangle patch object
recpatch = @(x,y,w,h,c) patch([x x+w x+w x],[y y y+h y+h], c ) ;

%// create your rectangle (and retrieve the handle if you want to set other properties later)
hp = recpatch(5,5,1,1,'k') ;
```

This rectangle will pass the test of rotation ;-)

Comment: I think all 2d objects are not drawn in any other than the standard 2d view.

Comment: @A.Donda. It depends what we call 2D objects. If you draw a line in a 2D plane (x,y), some call it 2D but it will still be rendered in a 3D view (and the same for the patch). It seems only the `rectangle` is a _pure_ 2D object in this sense then.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the axes ares swapped, but you're drawing a square so you don't notice that.
Try this and you'll notice the swap:

```
rectangle('Position',[5 5 2 1], 'FaceColor','k')
```

Comment: It's not that. Rectangle (or square in my case) is not even drawn at all. Have you tried to reproduce it in matlab?

Comment: I tested it and it was properly drawn.

Comment: Hm. Very wierd. Which matlab do you use? I have R2013b.

Comment: Check that the axes are correctly displayed. Try changing the rectangle location and dimensions

Comment: I already did. It's the same. I just tried with Matlab R2014b on other computer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rectangle('Position',[1 2 5 6])
axis([1 11 1 11])
```

Comment: I don't see how this makes any difference.

Comment: The difference comes at the the view line.